# Cancelling function by user action (html/template)

Tags: go, go-html-template

My goal is:

- have an html page with a `<a href>` to enable/disable a function
- when enabled: calling function: a sum in my example
- when disabled: stop / kill function called before

Two first points are OK (or feel free to tell me what I may improve)

But I have no idea how to do the third point (because way I used for first points is not good?)

```
    package main
    
    import (
        "html/template"
        "github.com/labstack/echo"
        "log"
        "io"
        "net/http"
        "strconv"
        "fmt"
        "time"
    )
    
    //init LOG
    func init(){
        log.SetPrefix("TRACE: ")
        log.SetFlags(log.Ldate | log.Ltime | log.Llongfile)
        log.Println("init started")
    }
    
    // main function
    func main() {
    
    // defining struct instance
    settings.Enabled = false
    
    // Parsing the required html
    // file in same directory
    // Parsing Templates
    t := &Template{
        templates: template.Must(template.ParseGlob("test.html")),
    }
    
    // standard output to print merged data
    
    e := echo.New()
    e.Renderer = t
    e.HideBanner = false
    e.HidePort = false
    e.Debug = true
    
    e.GET("/", index)
    e.GET("/toggleEnable", toggleEnable)
    
    e.Start("127.0.0.1" + ":" + strconv.Itoa(8080))
    
    }
    
    func index(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "index", settings)
    } 
    
    // Settings Type ...
    type Settings struct {
        Enabled bool
    }
    var settings Settings
    
    type Template struct {
        templates *template.Template
    }
    
    func (t *Template) Render(w io.Writer, name string, data interface{}, c echo.Context) error {
        return t.templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data)
    }
    
    func toggleEnable(c echo.Context) error {
        if settings.Enabled {
            settings.Enabled = false
        } else {
            settings.Enabled = true
            Sum()
        }
        return c.Redirect(http.StatusTemporaryRedirect, c.Request().Header.Get("Referer"))
    }
    
    func Sum() {
    
        sum := 0
        for i := 1; i < 50; i++ {
            sum += i
            fmt.Println(sum)
            time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        }
    
    }
```

and test.html:

````
``` 
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
       <head> 
          <title>Test</title> 
       </head> 
       <body> 
    {{define "index"}}
          <h1>Settings</h1>
          
             <p>Test enabled : <a href="/toggleEnable">{{.Enabled }}</a></p>
             
    {{end}}
       </body> 
    </html> 

```
````

For the moment, if I false -> true: sum works and if I true-> false: nothing happens and if I false -> true one more time: an other count begin.

Next step will be to display count in html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As currently written when the browser requests `/toggleEnable` nothing will be returned until `Sum()` completes (which will take around 150 seconds). After the `Sum()` is complete the page with `Test enabled : false` will be returned/displayed. If you want to provide the ability for the user to interrupt the process then it's probably best to run it in a Goroutine; something like this:

```
// Settings Type ...
type Settings struct {
    Enabled bool
    Stop chan struct{}
}
var settings Settings

type Template struct {
    templates *template.Template
}

func (t *Template) Render(w io.Writer, name string, data interface{}, c echo.Context) error {
    return t.templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data)
}

func toggleEnable(c echo.Context) error {
    if settings.Enabled {
        settings.Enabled = false
        close(settings.Stop)
    } else {
        settings.Enabled = true
        settings.Stop = make(chan struct{})
        go Sum(settings.Stop)
    }
    return c.Redirect(http.StatusTemporaryRedirect, c.Request().Header.Get("Referer"))
}

func Sum(stop chan struct{}) {
    sum := 0
    for i := 1; i < 50; i++ {
        sum += i
        fmt.Println(sum)
        select {
        case <-stop:
            fmt.Println("stopped")
            return
        case <-time.After(3 * time.Second):
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there are some issues with this. It is written on the assumption that there will be a single client and the page will not be updated when the timer completes (you would need to add a refresh or similar).

> Next step will be to display count in html page

To do this you will need a way for the browser to request updates. This could be through a [refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) (fairly simple but not a great user experience) or using Javascript (either polling or using websockets).

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works fine! I will now try to display count!

Comment: Note that I would like to have same display as in standard output.. :)

Comment: Maybe start by adding the numbers to a slice and including that on the page (you would need to manually refresh it to see them). Once you have that done you could look to make it more usable.